# Umemura's Theorem on Solving any Algebraic Polynomial Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, modular-forms, elliptic-integrals, theta-functions

I have recently read Bruce King's Beyond the Quartic Equation. In the last pages, he shows a theorem, Umemura's Theorem, which shows how to solve any polynomial equation. I have tried to understand the concepts behind, but failed. Then, I started searching everywhere I could and found these things:

- This is the only question (no answered by the way) I have seen in Stack about this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151498/understanding-umemuras-theorem-for-roots-of-algebraic-equations
- Something related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_formula
- And also Wiki pages about the topics mentioned bellow

As far as I went, it seems I need to understand what are:

1. Elliptic Functions/Integrals
2. Theta Functions
3. Modular Functions
4. Period Matrix
5. Theta Functions with those matrices filled up with zeros and ones (shown in the Thomae's formula link)
6. Higher Genus Theta Functions

I tried to read the wiki pages about these topics above, however, sometimes, I do not get a thing. Well, I'm here to ask your opinion on what to do, what and how should I attack first, since I only know Single-Variable, Multi-Variable and Vectorial Calculus, some ways of solving ODEs, Linear Algebra and that's it.

Of course, if you know any of these concepts and share with me or at least recommend something "easy" to read, I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-8176-4578-6_18. An advice :take things into a proper order. 1) $\theta$ functions cannot be properly understood if you don't have studied complex function theory beforehand. 2) Besides, the interest of expressing roots of polynomials in terms of $\theta$ functions is limited...

Comment: Why is it limited? People just do want to do it? Or is the difficulty of solving those integrals?

Comment: Looking for "closed-form" expressions in mathematics is not always worth the time spend on them : it can be a dead-end with no connections with other part of mathematics, as well on the theoretical and on the practical side (computation intricacies, as you guess it).

Comment: I see, it makes sense. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @JeanMarie There is a long tradition of it with rich connections to other parts of math in this case. Starting from Vieta's trig solution to the irreducible case of the cubic and Hermite-Klein-Kronecker solution to the quintic in terms of the elliptic modular function (and these cases are where I advise the OP to start). One can see from Umemura's paper that there is interesting algebra and algebraic geometry involved in the general case as well. [Klein's Lectures on Icosahedron](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059413439) is a classic exposition for the quintic.

Comment: @Conifold You are right. It was a large exaggeration of mine to say that in this case it was not fruitful ; on the contrary it has been historicaly (in particular) very fruitful. I only meant that for a newcomer in the field with a college level, it's not at all evident for him/her to grasp and benefit from the rich ideas therein (for example "Lectures on the icosahedron" is very very hard to read).